# For each group in a column, get only the rows with values in another column closest to a defined set

Tags: awk

I have a text file with 5 columns that are grouped by the content of the first column. The input data looks like this:

```
apple   1   1   1   1 
apple   2   1   2   2
apple   4   1   4   4.2
apple   4   1   4   4.5
apple   1   1   1   4.7 
apple   2   1   2   5
apple   3   1   3   6
apple   4   1   4   6.5
apple   1   1   1   6.8 
apple   2   1   2   7
apple   3   1   3   8
apple   4   1   4   8.5
apple   3   1   3   9
apple   4   1   4   10  
banana  25  4   4   1   
banana  35  10  14  1.9
banana  36  10  24  2.5
banana  37  10  34  2.6   
banana  35  10  14  4
banana  36  10  24  5.5
banana  37  10  34  5.8
banana  25  4   4   7.3   
banana  35  10  14  7.5
banana  36  10  24  8
banana  37  10  34  9
banana  37  10  34  10
```

For each group in column 1, I would like to get only the rows with values in the last column that are closest to numbers from 1 to 10.

For example, the first row selected for apple would be the row where the value in column 5 is the closest to 1. The second row selected would be the one where column 5 is closest to equalling 2, and so on up to 10. So regardless of how many rows there are for apple in the input, the final output will have 10 rows. From the example above, the desired output would look like this:

```
apple   1   1   1   1 
apple   2   1   2   2
apple   2   1   2   2
apple   4   1   4   4.2 
apple   2   1   2   5
apple   3   1   3   6
apple   2   1   2   7
apple   3   1   3   8
apple   3   1   3   9
apple   4   1   4   10  
banana  25  4   4   1   
banana  35  10  14  1.9
banana  37  10  34  2.6   
banana  35  10  14  4
banana  36  10  24  5.5
banana  37  10  34  5.8
banana  25  4   4   7.3   
banana  36  10  24  8
banana  37  10  34  9
banana  37  10  34  10
```

I have tried several variations of something like this, which gets me part of the way there, but I don't know how to iterate through based on the categories in first column.

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=10; i++) BEGIN{a=100} {aa=i-$5;if (aa<a && aa>0) {a=aa;n=$0}} END {print n}}' fruit.txt
```

Thanks for any suggestions - I'm learning as I go, so explanations or tips on syntax are always really appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts in form of code in your question keep it up. Coming to logic of getting expected output, could you please elaborate more on logic part to get expected output, as its not clear on what basis you want to ignore lines.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13! You're back to help me again - Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. I have tried to add some more explanation. I basically want to pull out the rows where the values of the last column are closest to the numbers from 1 to 10, so that I will always have 10 rows per fruit regardless of how many rows were in the input. I hope that makes at least a bit of sense!

Comment: I got the basic thought from this one, I believe your `banana` fruit 2nd line should have `2.5` rather than `1.9` right? Kindly do confirm me once, anyways I have added an answer here too, we could discuss there, cheers.

Comment: if you have a single line in the file `apple   1   1   1   1 ` do you expect 10 x `apple   1   1   1   1 ` in the output?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right @perreal! So when comparing 1 to numbers through 1-10, it will always be the closest number if it is the only entry. Every fruit must have 10 rows, even if rows are repeated to get that. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: So if the value closest to 2 was 3 you'd print `1 3 3 4 ...`? I feel like you could come up with better sample input/output that covers a lot more of your use cases.

Comment: You're right - I tried to keep it simple and kept it confusing instead. I've edited my origin example to hopefully make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Requires GNU awk for arrays of arrays.*

```
function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v}                  
                                                         
{                                                        
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {                            
    if (a[$1][i] == "" || abs(i - $5) < a[$1][i]) {      
      b[$1][i] = $0;                                     
      a[$1][i] = abs(i - $5)                             
    }                                                    
  }                                                      
}                                                        
                                                         
END {                                                    
  for (k in b) {                                         
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {                          
      print b[k][i]                                      
    }                                                    
  }                                                      
}
```

*Gives:*

```
apple   1   1   1   1
apple   2   1   2   2
apple   3   1   3   3
apple   4   1   4   4.2
apple   2   1   2   5
apple   3   1   3   6
apple   2   1   2   7
apple   3   1   3   8
apple   3   1   3   9
apple   4   1   4   10
banana  25  4   4   1
banana  35  10  14  1.9
banana  25  4   4   3
banana  35  10  14  4
banana  36  10  24  5
banana  37  10  34  6
banana  25  4   4   7.3
banana  36  10  24  8
banana  37  10  34  9
banana  37  10  34  10
```